# Python Graph Search -- Determine if successor(s) is closer to the goal than current node

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, traversal

I have a very simple graph:

```
graph = {
 "START": ["P3"],
 "P1":["P2", "P4","END"],
 "P2":["P1", "P3"],
 "P3":["P2", "P4", "END"],
 "P4":["P1","P3", "P5", "P6", "END"],
 "P5":["P4"],
 "P6":["P4", "P7", "P8", "P9"],
 "P7":["P6"],
 "P8":["P6"],
 "P9":["P6"]}
```

Example: Beginning from the `start` node its adjacent node will be `P3`, now `P3` is closer to the goal as compared to `start`, done by calling `is_closer_point(source=start, new=P3, target=end)`. After this `P3` will become the new "start" node and its adjacent nodes will be checked if they are closer to the goal than and so on.

I am not sure how I can implement this in python. Manually, it can be done like this:

```
step 0: check if P3 is closer to END than START (True)
step 1: Goto P3 and check if P2 and P4 are closer to the goal than P3 (True)
Step 2: Goto P2 check if P1 is closer (True) do not check P3 because is already checked 
Step 3: Goto P4 check P5 and P6 (False, False) ....

End Results should be: 
P1 = P2 = P3 = P4 = True
P5 = P6 = P7 = P8 = P9 = False
```

Here are the two functions used:

```
def is_closer_point(source, new, target, graph)->bool:
    source_paths = find_all_paths(graph, source, target)
    new_paths = find_all_paths(graph, new, target)
    return len(min(source_paths, key=len)) >= len(min(new_paths, key=len))

def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if start not in graph:
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```